# Тег div в summary\спойлере

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь запихнуть пример с галеерей [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp) под тег summary.

Выходит вот так, почему-то не раскрывается нормально и все сбивает:

До:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После открытия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

css gallery:

```
div.gallery {
    position:relative;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

css спойлера:

```
details[class="screenshot"] summary {
    font-size: 17px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
}
details[class="screenshot"][open] summary {
    background: #AC193D;
    color: #FFF;
}
details[class="screenshot"] summary:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    content: "";
    background-image: url(/images/spoiler.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 6px 6px;
}
```

Почему так выходит и как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, это происходит из-за свойства: `float: left;`

Попробуйте добавить `clear: both;` у ниже следующего блока
Или добавьте эти свойства спойлеру/галлерее:

```
.gallery:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Убрал float и всё стало ок. Спасибо.

Comment: Не подскажите теперь, как сделать чтоб элементы не друг под другом появлялись, а справа?

Comment: Нужно самим элементам добавить либо float: left; либо установить свойство display: inline-block;

Comment: Да, с display: inline-block;  эти дивы нормально отображаются. Спасибо большое, я не веб-разработчик, а css не всегда очень логичен :)